# Se sobreescriben campos que no son especificados a la hora de actualizar un atributo dentro de un objeto

Tags: c#, objeto, reflection

mi problema es el siguiente:
Estoy haciendo un endpoint el cual actualiza un "Informe" (estoy trabajando para una empresa de inmobiliaria y se manejan con informes, los cuale son literalmente forms las cuales contienen informacion, desde listas de personas, hasta objetos con gran cantidad de atributos dentro), y los datos a actualizar de dicho informe vienen en formato JSON.
Para dar un poco de contexto, esta es la clase del Informe que estoy tratando de actualizar:

```
public class InformeDominioMatriculadoP : Informe
{
    public int AnioEscritura { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Partido { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public string Matricula { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string UnidadFuncional { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? Poligono { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public NomenclaturaCatastral NomenclaturaCatastral { get; set; }
}
```

El atributo en cuestion al que quiero hacerle los cambios es el objeto "NomenclaturaCatastral", el cuale se ve así:

```
public class NomenclaturaCatastral
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Circunscripcion { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Seccion { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Chacra { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Quinta { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Fraccion { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Manzana { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Parcela { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? SubParcela { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? DesignacionTituloPlano { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? MedidasLinderos { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Superficie { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Observaciones { get; set; } = string.Empty;

}
```

El codigo del endpoint para actualizar es este:

```
    [HttpPut("updateInforme")]
    public ActionResult UpdateInforme(int id, dynamic informeParametro)
    {
        var informeAActualizar = _context.Informes.Find(id);

        // Deserializar informePorParametros en un JObject 
        var informeJObjectParametro = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(informeParametro.ToString());

        var informeCasteado = this.CastearInforme(informeAActualizar);

        if (informeCasteado != null)
        {
            // Actualizar los campos del informe a partir del informe recibido por parámetro
            foreach (var atributosJson in informeJObjectParametro.Properties())
            {
                if (atributosJson.Value.Type != JTokenType.Null)
                {
                    var nameAtributo = atributosJson.Name;
                    var nameAtributoUpper = char.ToUpper(nameAtributo[0]) + nameAtributo.Substring(1);
                    var propiedad = informeCasteado.GetType().GetProperty(nameAtributoUpper);
                    var value = atributosJson.Value.ToObject(propiedad.PropertyType);
                    propiedad.SetValue(informeCasteado, value);
                    
                    //El atributo es un objeto?
                    if (atributosJson.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                    {
                        var objeto = (JObject)atributosJson.Value;
                        foreach (var item in objeto.Properties())
                        {
                            if (item.Type != JTokenType.Null)
                            {
                                var objetoNameAtributoUpper = char.ToUpper(item.Name[0]) + item.Name.Substring(1);
                                var objetoPropiedad = propiedad.PropertyType.GetProperty(objetoNameAtributoUpper);
                                var objetoValue = item.Value.ToObject(objetoPropiedad.PropertyType);
                                objetoPropiedad.SetValue(propiedad.GetValue(informeCasteado), objetoValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(new { message = "Informe modificado con éxito.", status = "success" });
        }
        return BadRequest(new { message = "Datos ingresados erróneos.", status = "error" });
    }
```

Como pueden ver, los atributos a actualizar me llegan en un dynamic y dependiendo del Informe que se seleccionó para editar, me lo castea a dicho tipo de Informe (ya que hay muchos Informes distintos, los cuales heredan de la clase padre Informe), el atributo dentro de "NomenclaturaCatastral" que estoy tratando de editar es el siguiente (en formato JSON):

```
{
    "nomenclaturaCatastral": {
        "observaciones": "Prueba de cambio"
    }
}
```

El objeto "NomenclaturaCatastral" del informe, previo a que haga ese cambio:

```
"nomenclaturaCatastral": {
        "id": 0,
        "circunscripcion": "DATO RANDOM",
        "seccion": "DATO RANDOM",
        "chacra": "DATO RANDOM",
        "quinta": "DATO RANDOM",
        "fraccion": "",
        "manzana": "DATO RANDOM",
        "parcela": "",
        "subParcela": "DATO RANDOM",
        "designacionTituloPlano": "DATO RANDOM",
        "medidasLinderos": "",
        "superficie": "",
        "observaciones": ""
    }
```

El Informe editado luego de hacer ese udpate me queda así (por practicidad solo muestro el atributo "NomenclaturaCatastral"):

```
"nomenclaturaCatastral": {
        "id": 0,
        "circunscripcion": "",
        "seccion": "",
        "chacra": "",
        "quinta": "",
        "fraccion": "",
        "manzana": "",
        "parcela": "",
        "subParcela": "",
        "designacionTituloPlano": "",
        "medidasLinderos": "",
        "superficie": "",
        "observaciones": "Prueba de cambio"
    }
```

Ya sinceramente me cansé de probar cambios y debuggear. Entiendo que el problema está en que le estoy seteando al objeto NomenclaturaCatastral literalmente solo 1 atributo de todos los que tiene, entonces se sobreescribe. Pero no se me ocurre otra forma de hacer las cosas, de antemano les agradezco por cualquier ayuda que me puedan ofrecer!